# Рекурсивный многопоточный обход директорий

Tags: c#, многопоточность, рекурсия

Подскажите, как лучше организовать взаимодействие двух потоков при рекурсивном обходе директорий? Допустим, первый поток рекурсивно обходит эти самые директории, а второй, получая информацию от первого потока (допустим через коллекцию) вносит эти директории в элемент на форме (TreeView).

Comment: Лучше всего сделать "как-то" (желательно почитав перед этим что-нибудь в Интернете), после чего, если результат не удовлетворит, обратиться на соответствующий ресурс (не SO) с просьбой оптимизировать код.

Comment: Обходить лучше не рекурсивно: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2107294/1985167, плюс см. сравнение по скорости в самом вопросе.

Comment: почти в два раза можно ускорить обход, если использовать WinAPI. пример на c# [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482449/#482450)

Answer (score 3):

Какой смысл распараллеливать то, что в одном потоке будет работать быстрее за счёт более линенйного обращения к диску?

Можно попытатся вынести в один поток получение, а в другой - вывод на формк.

Можно в параллельных потоках запустить обработку для разных физических(!) дисков.

Ну и обходить каталоги надо самому рекурсивно с обработкой исключений доступа.

Comment: Автор вопроса и не говорит о распараллеливании обхода. А о взаимодействии двух потоков -- один обходит, другой выводит.

Comment: _"в одном потоке будет работать быстрее за счёт более линенйного обращения к диску"_ -- а для SSD это правило применимо?

Comment: @Stack, не знаю. На момент измерений ssd ещё ни у кого не было. Если есть, можешь проверить и сказать.

Answer (score 3):

Для решения задач, в которых один из потоков является поставщиком данных (обходит каталоги), а второй - потребителем (отображает имена каталогов на форме), можно использовать `ConcurrentQueue<T>`. Например, так:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> _dirsQueue =
        new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

    private volatile bool _enumerationEnded;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void EnumerateDirsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _enumerationEnded = false;
        new Thread(EnumerateDirs).Start();
        new Thread(ShowDirs).Start();
    }

    private void ShowDirs()
    {
        while (!_enumerationEnded || _dirsQueue.Count != 0)
        {
            string dir;
            if (_dirsQueue.TryDequeue(out dir))
            {
                InvokeInUIThread(DirsListBox, () => DirsListBox.Items.Add(dir));
            }
        }
    }

    private void EnumerateDirs()
    {
        try
        {
            EnumerateDirs("c:\\");
            _enumerationEnded = true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // handle exception
        }
    }

    private void EnumerateDirs(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path);
            foreach (var dir in dirs)
            {
                _dirsQueue.Enqueue(dir);
                EnumerateDirs(dir);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // handle exception
        }
    }

    private void InvokeInUIThread(Control control, Action action)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            control.Invoke(action);
        }
        else
        {
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

При этом при обходе каталогов надо учитывать права доступа и обрабатывать соответствующие исключения. Неплохой пример обхода дерева каталогов можно найти [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx). Также хочу отметить, что доступ к элементу Windows Forms возможен только из того треда, в котором этот элемент создан, поэтому добавлен метод `InvokeInUIThread`.

В данном примере (отображение каталогов на форме) можно воспользоваться [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) (если доступен .NET 4.5), что упростит код (и автоматически синхронизирует тред, из которого надо обращаться к UI):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void EnumerateDirsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await EnumerateDirs("c:\\");
    }

    private async Task EnumerateDirs(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path);
            foreach (var dir in dirs)
            {
                DirsListBox.Items.Add(dir);
                await EnumerateDirs(dir);
                await Task.Delay(1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

`Task.Delay(1)` добавлен, чтобы список успевал перерисовываться.