# Отказано в доступе при использовании Directory.GetFiles

Tags: c#, .net, файлы

Я хочу получить список файлов, которые находятся во вложенных директориях и использую:

```
Directory.GetFiles(string,string,SearchOption)
```

Но через какое-то время я получаю ошибку: "Отказано в доступе".

Я посмотрел в дебагере и обнаружил, что `Directory.GetFiles` натыкается на какие-то скрытые системные папки, которые мне в принципе не нужны.

Можно ли как-нибудь задать игнорирование подобных папок?

Если я оберну все в `try/catch`, то боюсь, что я не получу нужны мне список.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Взял отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172544/ignore-folders-files-when-directory-getfiles-is-denied-access)

```
private List<string> GetFiles(string path, string pattern)
{
    var files = new List<string>();

    try 
    { 
        files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));
        foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
            files.AddRange(GetFiles(directory, pattern));
    } 
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }

    return files;
}
```

Функция рекурсивная. При составлении списка файлов будут учитываться обыкновенные папки, а системные не учитываться. Не должно быть такого, что из-за Eхception в конечный результат не войдут обыкновенные файлы.

---

```
Console.WriteLine("Started: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

var fileList = GetFiles("c:\\", "*.*");

Console.WriteLine("Finished: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
Console.WriteLine("Files count: " + fileList.Count);

// У меня так:
// Started: 12:43:05
// Finished: 12:44:33
// Files count: 427083
```

Comment: Плюс: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/430875/106