# SearchOption.AllDirectories (Exceptions) C# \ как не лазить в системные папки

Tags: c#, winforms

Делаю вот такой поиск по папкам

```
    {
       treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

        try {
            foreach (string find in Directory.GetFiles(catalog, fileName, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                fileCount++;
                label6.Text = "Файлов обработано: " + fileCount;
                label4.Text = "Обработка: " + find;

                treeView1.Nodes.Add("" + find);


            }
        }
        catch
        {   
            treeView1.Nodes.Add("123");
        }
        fileCount = 0;
        }
```

Естественно во многих случиях вылазит Exception после чего поиск по папкам прекращается. Как продолжить поиск после ексепшена, либо же как сделать что бы поиск не проводился в системных директориях вызывающих exception?

Comment: самое простое, try/catch внутри foreach.

Comment: Да, я натыкался на эту инфу на зарубежном форуме и пробовал, но чего-то не катит...)  
В этом случае вылазит необработанный ексепшн:
Необработанное исключение типа "System.UnauthorizedAccessException" в mscorlib.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Отказано в доступе по пути "E:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-1046610997-2961191853-1124677420-1000".

Answer (score 1):

1. `try/catch` внутри `foreach`.
2. Не использовать флаг `SearchOption.AllDirectories`, а использовать `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` и прогонять рекурсивно.

Comment: благодарю, а можно уточнить пример рекурсии в данном случае?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437404/15479