# Как организовать вывод, чтобы не зависало окно?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Есть функция, которая сканирует все файлы, каталоги и подкаталоги.
Нужно, чтобы в процессе сканирования, обработанные строки выводились в textbox в реальном времени.
Знаю, что это надо с помощью нового потока реализовывать, но почему-то форма всё равно виснет.

```
// Вызов функции
public void GO_OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    new Thread(x => ProcessDirectory(Dispatcher.Invoke(() => currDir = new DirectoryInfo(PathBox.Text)))).Start();
}

private void ProcessDirectory(DirectoryInfo newDir) {
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        foreach(DirectoryInfo d in newDir.GetDirectories()) {
            while(check) {
                resultBox.AppendText(newDir.FullName + "\n");
                foreach(FileInfo f in newDir.GetFiles()) {
                    resultBox.AppendText(f.Name + "\n");
                    if(TemplateBox.Text == "") {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if(f.Name.Contains(TemplateBox.Text)) {
                        string sf = f.FullName.Remove(f.FullName.LastIndexOf(TemplateBox.Text), TemplateBox.Text.Length);
                        if(File.Exists(sf)) {
                            sf = sf.Insert(sf.LastIndexOf('.'), "(ex)");
                            File.Move(f.FullName, sf);
                        }
                        else
                            File.Move(f.FullName, sf);
                        }
                        resultBox.ScrollToEnd();
                    }
                    check = false;
                }
                resultBox.AppendText(d.FullName + "\n");
                foreach(FileInfo f in d.GetFiles()) {
                    resultBox.AppendText("------Sub file: " + f.Name + "\n");
                    if(TemplateBox.Text == "") {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if(f.Name.Contains(TemplateBox.Text)) {
                        string sf = f.FullName.Remove(f.FullName.LastIndexOf(TemplateBox.Text), TemplateBox.Text.Length);
                        if(File.Exists(sf)) {
                            sf = sf.Insert(sf.LastIndexOf('.'), "(ex)");
                            File.Move(f.FullName, sf);
                        }
                        else
                            File.Move(f.FullName, sf);
                    }
                    resultBox.ScrollToEnd();
                }

                new Thread(x => ProcessDirectory(d)).Start();

                if(TemplateBox.Text == "")
                    continue;
                else if(d.Name.Contains(TemplateBox.Text)) {
                    string s = d.FullName.Remove(d.FullName.LastIndexOf(TemplateBox.Text), TemplateBox.Text.Length);
                    if(Directory.Exists(s)) {
                        s += "(ex)";
                        Directory.Move(d.FullName, s);
                    }
                    else
                        Directory.Move(d.FullName, s);
                }

                resultBox.ScrollToEnd();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Потому что почти весь код исполняется в Dispatcher.Invoke - т. е. в потоке GUI. А нужно только вывод в TextBox там сделать.

Comment: Так без этого будет ошибка, мол элементы принадлежат другому потоку

Comment: В Dispatcher.Invoke должно быть только присвоение someTextBox.Text = someValue; и всё! Но не весь код.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. :) Но меня не покидает чувство, что это какие-то костыли и всё совершенно неправильно оформленно, везде эти диcпетчеры натыканы...

Comment: @PiPiPARU если в общем -- то все верно. Вы вынесли код в отдельный поток, чтобы UI не тормозил, а диспетчер нужен, чтобы обновить прогресс в UI. Единственное что я бы посоветовал вам отказаться от использования `Thread.Start()` и почитать про `Task.Run()` и `async/await` (оно же позволит отказаться от диспетчера, если все правильно сделать). Вот тут уже обсуждалось, как пробегать по файлам, там в т.ч. есть асинхронная версия: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431921/106

Comment: @PiPiPARU как более простой вариант -- `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`.

Answer (score 1):

Вынесено из комментариев:

> Виснет потому что почти весь код исполняется в Dispatcher.Invoke - т. е. в потоке GUI. А нужно только вывод в TextBox там делать, например, someTextBox.Text = someValue; и всё.