# DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles => Исключение

Tags: c#, .net

Нужно получить все файлы по заданной маске. Метод EnumerateFiles выдает исключение, если какой-то файл имеет системные права доступа. Как это обойти?

```
var sourceDir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
foreach (var f in sourceDir.EnumerateFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
     var lvItem = new ListViewItem(Path.GetFileName(f.FullName), 0);
     lvItem.SubItems.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(f.FullName));
     var fileInfo = new FileInfo(f.FullName);
     lvItem.SubItems.Add(fileInfo.Length + " байт");
     lvItem.SubItems.Add(Directory.GetLastWriteTime(f.FullName).ToShortDateString());
     uiContext.Send(d => listView1.Items.Add(lvItem), null);
}
```

Comment: Судя по всему, ничего лучше ручной рекурсии с отловом исключений нет.

Comment: Рекурсивный обход. Пример можно посмотреть тут (многопоточность можете в расчет не брать): http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431921/106

Comment: Мне кажется здесь метка [tag:winforms] не к месту, лучше бы её заменить на [tag:.net]

Comment: @Bald56rus в коде вопроса используется класс `ListViewItem` из `System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: @МстиславПавлов <зануда>а в тексте вопроса нет, данный вопрос можно решить без участия компонентов [tag:winforms], ведь проблема же не в добавлении списка в компонент а в обходе директории</зануда>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по всему, ничего лучше ручной рекурсии с отловом исключений нет.

Можно попробовать так:

```
static IEnumerable<FileInfo> EnumerateFilesDeepIgnoringAccessException(
    DirectoryInfo root, string mask)
{
    var localResult = new List<FileInfo>();
    try
    {
        localResult = root.EnumerateFiles(mask).ToList();
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        // ignore it
        yield break;
    }

    foreach (var fi in localResult)
        yield return fi;

    foreach (var di in root.EnumerateDirectories())
    {
        foreach (var fi in EnumerateFilesDeepIgnoringAccessException(di, mask))
            yield return fi;
    }
}
```

Код основан на [официальном примере](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413343%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), модифицирован для ленивого обхода.

---

Можно ещё избавиться от рекурсии стандартным путём — добавить явную очередь каталогов для обхода. Однако не думаю, что это даст существенный выигрыш по скорости по сравнению с обходом файловой системы.

---

Специфически для вашего кода, я не стал бы заниматься обходом файловой системы в том же потоке, в котором бежит UI — иначе зависаний не избежать. Вам стоит подумать об обходе в отдельном потоке.

Comment: _"localResult = root.EnumerateFiles(mask).ToList();"_ -- если файлов 10000. в них только 10-й выдает UnauthorizedAccess, то что будет в localResult?

Comment: @Stack: `UnauthorizedAccess` выдаёт не получение `FileInfo`, а доступ к `root`. То есть, это случится не на 10-ом файле, а до первого.

Comment: _"UnauthorizedAccess выдаёт не получение FileInfo, а доступ к root"_ -- если так, то до ToList() вызов не доходит. и он же не нужен?

Comment: и с файлами может быть PathTooLongException

Comment: @Stack: `EnumerateFiles` возвращает ленивую последовательность, поэтому вполне возможно, что исключение будет выброшено лишь при попытке энумерации. Это было бы логично: доступ к файловой системе для проверки прав не должен происходить до начала фактической энумерации (иначе теряется смысл ленивости). (Впрочем, я не проверял.)

Comment: @Stack: Угу. А ещё `ArgumentException`, `ArgumentNullException`, `DirectoryNotFoundException` и `IOException`. Мне лень ловить их все.

Comment: @VladD,  Ленивая последовательность? Под этим вы подразумеваете какой-то алгоритм или что?

Comment: @Lightness: Ленивая последовательность — это последовательность, которая вычисляется реально лишь при перечислении. Вы можете проверить: напишите в коде `var seq = EnumerateFilesDeepIgnoringAccessException(...); Thread.Sleep(30000); foreach (var entry in seq) Console.WriteLine(entry);`. Во время `Sleep`'а добавьте файл, и вы увидите его в выводе.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public sealed class FileSystemEnumerable : IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo>
{    
    private readonly DirectoryInfo _root;
    private readonly IList<string> _patterns;
    private readonly SearchOption _option;

    public FileSystemEnumerable(DirectoryInfo root, string pattern, SearchOption option)
    {
        _root = root;
        _patterns = new List<string> { pattern };
        _option = option;
    }

    public FileSystemEnumerable(DirectoryInfo root, IList<string> patterns, SearchOption option)
    {
        _root = root;
        _patterns = patterns;
        _option = option;
    }

    public IEnumerator<FileSystemInfo> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (_root == null || !_root.Exists) yield break;

        IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> matches = new List<FileSystemInfo>();
        try
        {
            foreach (var pattern in _patterns)
            {
                matches = matches.Concat(_root.EnumerateDirectories(pattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
                                 .Concat(_root.EnumerateFiles(pattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        catch (PathTooLongException ptle)
        {
            yield break;
        } catch (System.IO.IOException e)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        foreach (var file in matches)
        {
            yield return file;
        }

        if (_option == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        {
            foreach (var dir in _root.EnumerateDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
                var fileSystemInfos = new FileSystemEnumerable(dir, _patterns, _option);
                foreach (var match in fileSystemInfos)
                {
                    yield return match;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
var root = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var searchPattern = @"*.txt";
var searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories;
var enumerable = new FileSystemEnumerable(root, searchPattern, searchOption);
```