# Как распараллелить рекурсивный поиск файлов в папках?

Tags: c#, parallel

Как распараллелить процесс поиска по папкам?

```
public  IEnumerable<string> GetDirectoryFiles(string rootPath, string patternMatch, SearchOption searchOption)
{
    
    var foundFiles = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

    if (searchOption == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<string> subDirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(rootPath);
            foreach (string dir in subDirs)
            {
                foundFiles = foundFiles.Concat(GetDirectoryFiles(dir, patternMatch, searchOption)); // Add files in subdirectories recursively to the list
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex) { LoggingExtensions.WriteDebug(ex.Message); }
        catch (PathTooLongException ex) { LoggingExtensions.WriteDebug(ex.Message); }
    }

    try
    {
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootPath, patternMatch);
        foundFiles = foundFiles.Concat(files); 
        var z = foundFiles.Distinct().ToList();
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex) { LoggingExtensions.WriteDebug(ex.Message); }
    return foundFiles;
}
```

Comment: Вообще конечно можно, ведь это обычный поиск в ширину\глубину. Но 1) зачем параллелить именно рекурсивный вариант? 2) Надо ли вообще параллелить работу с жестким диском? 3) Собираетесь ли вы контроллировать уровень параллелизма?

Comment: [Дубликат?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/430875/220553)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ чет не похоже. Там больше про producer\consumer, тут про многопоточность

Comment: @tym32167 мне в принципе без разницы хоть рекурсивно - хоть нет. У меня 20к папок и в ней туева куча подпапок. Хочется просто через Parallel For запустить по максимуму и всё

Comment: Доступ к накопителю (не важно - HDD, SSD, CD/DVD) всё равно последовательный, поэтому от параллелизации толку практически не будет. Параллелить нужно не IO-доступ, а CPU-задачи.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а для SSD это точно без разницы? Пошел гуглить, вот в [ответе кто-то измерения проводил](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13422318/7612728) на скорость чтения. SSD показал лучшие значения.

Comment: При многократном поиске можно прикрутить кеширование и какой-нибудь `FileSystemWatcher` в фоне

Comment: А ещё лучше будет заменить здесь рекурсию на цикл, не факт что значительно быстрее будет, но какая-никакая оптимизация

Comment: @SmorcIRL замена рекурсии на цикл мало что ускорит, так как основная потеря времени тут на работу с жестврим диском. Но если хочется улучшить, то можно, например, учитывать семантические ссылки при поиске, чтобы не уйти в StackOverflow

Comment: Я проверил - убираете строчку `var z = foundFiles.Distinct().ToList();` и оно начинает раз в 5 работать быстрее.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov поиск по имени файла в случае NTFS - это поиск по B-Tree, которое с большой вероятностью будет лежать в кэше. Это CPU задача? :)

Comment: @PashaPash - насколько я понимаю, эту операцию - поиск по B-Tree - выполнит драйвер и распараллеливание никак её не улучшит.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У меня достаточно быстрый SSD. Как бы я не пытался распараллелить выполнение поиска, оно все равно съедает только один процессор, то есть вся работа ведется где-то драйвером в одном потоке, а мои потоки в приложении просто висят и ждут результатов этой работы. Но так как оверхед на асинхронность и спавн потоков получается весьма существенный, так как я выполнял поиск по всему диску `C:\`, то и выполнение метода затягивается и получается дольше.

Пробовал так же разбить сканирование директорий и получение файлов. При чем первое я выполнял синхронно в массив строк, а затем итерировал готовый массив чтобы поискать во всех доступных каталогах файлы. Прироста производительности так же не получилось, а вместо этого только просадка из-за того же асинхронного оверхеда.

Поэтому ответ на ваш вопрос: **Распараллеливание здесь бесполезно из-за особенностей работы драйвера файловой системы.**

Из вышеизложенного вывод: стоит сфокусироваться на оптимизации, а не на распараллеливании, так как оптимизация может дать больший прирост, чем распараллеливание.

Основная проблема вашего метода из вопроса - это то, что он сначала полностью отрабатывает, а затем только возвращает `IEnumerable` вызывающему методу. То есть сначала отработают все рекурсии, а потом только вы сможете проитерировать результаты. Если быть точнее, то возврат из метода произойдет только тогда, когда отработают все `.Concat`. Это можно исправить и получать результаты по мере их возвращения файловой системой.

Вторая проблема - баг, неиспользуемая переменная `z`, вычисления значения которой надо сгенерировать массив, но вы далее ничего с этой переменной не делаете, так что можно просто удалить строчку `var z = foundFiles.Distinct().ToList();`.

Третья проблема - это то что метод пытается получить файлы из директории, к которой уже известно, что нет доступа. В результате метод генерирует в 2 раза больше исключений, чем могло бы быть в идеале.

После оптимизации рекурсивный метод выглядит вот так:

```cs
public IEnumerable<string> GetDirectoryFiles(string rootPath, string patternMatch, SearchOption searchOption)
{
    bool dirSuccess = true;
    if (searchOption == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    {
        dirSuccess = false;
        IEnumerable<string> subDirs = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        try
        {
            subDirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(rootPath);
            dirSuccess = true;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex) { LoggingExtensions.WriteDebug(ex.Message); }
        catch (PathTooLongException ex) { LoggingExtensions.WriteDebug(ex.Message); }

        foreach (string dir in subDirs)
        {
            foreach (string path in GetDirectoryFiles(dir, patternMatch, searchOption))
            {
                yield return path;
            }
        }
    }

    // нет смысла пытаться запрашивать файлы, если нет доступа к каталогу или возникла другая ошибка
    if (dirSuccess)
    {
        foreach (string path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootPath, patternMatch))
        {
            yield return path;
        }
    }
}
```

Что можно оптимизировать дальше? То же что и всегда, когда я сталкиваюсь с рекурсивными методами - избавиться от рекурсии. Я попробовал механизмы с массивами и итерированием по большому массиву - особого прироста не получил, а получил его только от метода `Directory.EnumerateDirectories` с непосредственной передачей параметра `SearchOption` в него. То есть задачу поиска переложил наполовину на .NET, и вот тогда прирост стал ощутимым, хоть и не фантастическим.

Реализация без рекурсии:

```cs
public IEnumerable<string> GetDirectoryFilesFast(string rootPath, string patternMatch, SearchOption searchOption)
{
    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootPath, patternMatch))
    {
        yield return file;
    }
    if (searchOption == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    {
        IEnumerator<string> enumarator = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(rootPath, string.Empty, searchOption).GetEnumerator();
        while (true)
        {
            bool skip = true;
            try
            {
                if (!enumarator.MoveNext())
                    break;
                skip = false;
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex) { LoggingExtensions.WriteDebug(ex.Message); }
            catch (PathTooLongException ex) { LoggingExtensions.WriteDebug(ex.Message); }

            if (skip)
                continue;

            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(enumarator.Current, patternMatch))
            {
                yield return file;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Да и сам метод стал выглядеть проще.

Ну и измерил производительность на релизном билде.

Завел класс логирования. Так как мне нужна только статистика ошибок, то я просто их посчитаю, и не буду никуда выводить.

```cs
public static class LoggingExtensions
{
    public static int ErrorsCount { get; set; }
    public static void WriteDebug(string text) { ErrorsCount++; }
}
```

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("GetDirectoryFiles");
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    int i = 0;
    LoggingExtensions.ErrorsCount = 0;
    foreach (string path in GetDirectoryFiles(@"C:\", "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) { i++; }
    Console.WriteLine($"Found {i} files");
    Console.WriteLine($"{LoggingExtensions.ErrorsCount} exceptions thrown");
    TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - date;
    Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed {elapsed.TotalSeconds}s");

    Console.WriteLine("GetDirectoryFilesOriginal");
    date = DateTime.Now;
    i = 0;
    LoggingExtensions.ErrorsCount = 0;
    foreach (string path in GetDirectoryFilesOriginal(@"C:\", "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) { i++; }
    Console.WriteLine($"Found {i} files");
    Console.WriteLine($"{LoggingExtensions.ErrorsCount} exceptions thrown");
    elapsed = DateTime.Now - date;
    Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed {elapsed.TotalSeconds}s");

    Console.WriteLine("GetDirectoryFilesFast");
    date = DateTime.Now;
    i = 0;
    LoggingExtensions.ErrorsCount = 0;
    foreach (string path in GetDirectoryFilesFast(@"C:\", "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) { i++; }
    Console.WriteLine($"Found {i} files");
    Console.WriteLine($"{LoggingExtensions.ErrorsCount} exceptions thrown");
    elapsed = DateTime.Now - date;
    Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed {elapsed.TotalSeconds}s");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Ваш метод из вопроса назван здесь `GetDirectoryFilesOriginal` и для чистоты эксперимента я воткнул его в неизменном виде в середину, ну чтобы не казалось, что он отработал медленнее из-за того что первое обращение к директориям еще не кешировано и работает медленнее. В моем конкретном случае это не так.

И получил вот такой вывод (релизный билд с оптимизацией кода):

```
GetDirectoryFiles
Found 2612 files
287 exceptions thrown
Elapsed 89,225523s
GetDirectoryFilesOriginal
Found 2612 files
574 exceptions thrown
Elapsed 440,9526969s
GetDirectoryFilesFast
Found 2612 files
287 exceptions thrown
Elapsed 69,9758348s
```

Пришлось запастись терпением, чтобы дождаться окончания работы вашего метода. В итоге полная оптимизация ускорила работу метода **в 6,3 раза**.

**Так что решение вашей проблемы - не распараллеливание, а оптимизация.**

Comment: ssd m2 или sata? (плюсик за проделанную работу, было интересно)

Comment: @Andrew SATAII, спасибо, я еще пару багов подправил

Comment: Жаль, лучше такой тест проводить на м2 где меньше ограничение по шине.

Comment: @Andrew оно в любом случае не нагружает у меня SSD, а упирается в процессор. Так что при прочих равных на моей машине будет примерно фиолетово, M2 там у меня или SATAII.

Answer (score 7):

Фух, придётся дать свой ответ.

@aepot дал комментарий, что при удалении строки `var z = foundFiles.Distinct().ToList();` код начинает раз в 5 работать быстрее.

Почему так получается, откуда ускорение работы? Дело в том, что пока процессор выполняет эту строку кода, нет новых обращений к диску за новой порцией данных. То есть накопитель простаивает.

Удаляем эту строку - получаем более частые IO-запросы.

Именно в этом случае распараллеливание может помочь: один поток прочитал порцию данных и какое-то время обрабатывает их, в это время другой поток читает данные. Потом второй поток обрабатывает данные, а первый снова читает. Соответственно, чем больше длится обработка данных, тем больше смысла в увеличении количества потоков (распараллеливании).

Но не стоит путать это с прямым распараллеливанием **доступа** к накопителю! Если несколько потоков будут вхолостую читать данные (и никак не использовать их), то они просто будут ждать в очереди.

---

Полагаю, шаблон producer-consumer является классическим решением проблемы долгой обработки данных: один-единственный поток читает данные с накопителя и складывает их в некую коллекцию, другой(ие) поток(и) берут данные из этой коллекции и обрабатывают. При этом ни один поток не ждёт своей очереди поработать с диском.

Answer (score 5):

## (Не совсем ответ / Или совсем не ответ)

Распаралеливание работы с HDD бесполезное занятие. В любом случае ты упираешся в скорость винчестера. А при множестве потоков общая скорость задач **даже упадет**. Это связано с тем что несколько операций чтения и записи имеют одинаковый приоритет и постоянно нужно перемещать головку для каждого потока на другое место. А перемещение головки = утраты времени на лишнюю работу.

В случае с SSD все не так однозначно. Теоретический прирост может быть, а может быть краткострочный прирост скорости, а может и вовсе не будет прироста. Нельзя сказать просто "на ССД это будет работать быстрее" ибо ссд ссд рознь. Взять китайский низкоклассовый ссд - там операция записи будет 70-80 мегабайт (честная, а не по CrystalDiskMark, который лжет как дышит). Операция чтения - как повезет. Но около 300-350 (надеюсь).

Если брать SSD средней ценовой категории - там залепливают дыры отвратного железа добавлением кеша. Поэтому скорость записи будет хорошая пока не забьется кеш. А дальше будет печаль.

Если брать топовый ссд вроде самсунг Эво - там будет +- честная скорость на всем ссд.

Уверен, там есть еще какие-то особенности про которые я не знаю.

Еще могут быть разные виды RAID-ов. Там изменения скорости паралельной записи будет зависеть еще и от вида рейда.

---

## Оффтоп:

Не пользуйтесь CrystalDiskMark вообще. Это отвратный бенчмарк который не показывает обьективную оценку работы SSD от слова "вообще".

---

## Резюме:

Вобщем, даже если написать алгоритм распаралеливания мы можем получить в части случаев замедление вместо желаемого убыстрения.

А что бы наверняка понять стоит ли это делать - нужно провести множество тестов с РАЗНЫМИ SSD разных ценовых категорий на разных задачах. И только потом уже будет понятно есть ли смысл в это ввязыватся при конкретной задаче и какие костыли писать что бы это не приводило к замедлениям у конечного пользователя.

---

Лично я бы вообще не паралелил бы I/O задачи в принципе.

Comment: поиск файлов в папках != работа с SSD / HDD. Там вполне может быть какая-то часть CPU нагрузки. И к тому же, это ведь поиск по MFT, а не по содержимому файлов. В случае NTFS - это поиск по B-Tree, которое скорее всего будет в кэше лежать. Поиск по нему - это CPU-задача, и ее можно параллелить. Тот же SQL Server, в котором индексы - это лежащие на диске / в кэше B-Tree, и в нем параллелизм запросов внезапно работает. Так что не все так однозначно. Нужно взять и померять.

Comment: В MFT данные тоже лежать не последовательно, на сколько я понимаю. То есть если в паралели это делать, то вероятно, тоже приведет к замедлению потому что нужно будет заново проверять по списку какие именно файлы относятся к проверяемому пути или нет... А если это несколько потоков - то нужно проверять те же подпути по N раз.... Не уверен как именно это там работает, это теоретически. Что до кеширования - тоже тот еще вопрос. Думаю тут мы можем еще упереться в какие-то настройки винды дополнительно....

Comment: Короче) Суть моего ответа все равно сводилась к тому что нужны тесты. Еще и с разным железом. А теперь еще и с разными настройками винды ахахах. (Хотя на самом деле я не уверен что MFT кешируется... Это должно быть и так максимально оптимально реализовано из коробки... В теории.). А еще это может быть не только NTFS. Это тоже нужно учитывать - может быть под виндой и FAT и REFS, например. И хрен его знает как это работает там. Особенно учитывая что в REFS еще и поддержка дедупликации файлов есть...Что практически наверняка как-то сказалось на особенностях MFT и поиска....

Comment: Имхо, это **совсем** не ответ. Автор спрашивает **как** распараллелить.

Comment: Гм, а какая разница, дешманский или элитный SSD: в любом случае он будет показывать свою максимальную скорость при доступе в один поток. И добавление новых потоков ничего не изменит.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov иногда на SO принимают ответ который не отвечает на заданный вопрос в буквальном смысле) Никогда такого не видел?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov смотря на каком количестве данных замерять))) Дешманский без кеша будет показывать реальную скорость. средней ценовой категории будет показывать на небольшом количестве данных скорость кеша(а не памяти ССД), а потом начнется график в виде гребня потому что кеш то освобождается то занимается полностью и ссд начинает с данными работать напрямую. Короче, проверь сам и увидишь разницу)

Comment: Да, конечно. И я считаю вполне оправданным дать ответ, который в корне отличается от того, что просит автор (например, автор спрашивает "как распарсить html регулярками", а ему приводят решение с парсером). Но вас понесло совсем не в ту степь. Причём тут классовость ssd и обличение CrystalMark?

Comment: OK, дешёвый ssd отдаёт 50 МБ/с. Добавляем второй поток - в каждом получаем по 25 МБ/с. Суммарно ничего не изменилось. Берём дорогой ssd - 500 Мб/с. Добавляем второй поток - получаем по 250 Мб/с. Суммарно - то же самое. Попытка распараллеливания не зависит от того, к какому накопителю - хорошему или плохому - мы обращаемся.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Возможно, ты и прав. Я не проверял и не могу ни согласится ни опровергнуть это со сколь-нибуть весомыми доводами. Что до того что меня "понесло не в ту степь" - это были обьяснения почему с SSD не все так однозначно как в случае с HDD. Написал бы я только эту фразу - хрен кто бы понял что я имею ввиду.

Comment: Это я понимаю. Меня тоже постоянно заносит и я "растекаюсь мыслию по древу".

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov если ты прав, то распаралеливание не повлияет на скорость. Если прав я - это в отдельных случаях замедлит работу а на отдельных даст прирост (что нужно подтвердить разными тестами на разном железе). Но при этом мы еще имеем случаи когда программисты говорят про убыстрение на отдельных задачах IO работы с SSD при распаралеливании ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421767/multithread-read-from-disk/13422318#13422318 ). Что уже противоречит твоим теоретическим словам. Как они меряли и почему у них так вышло я, например, говорить не берусь - знаний не хватает.

Comment: И при этом еще могут быть нюансы еще и с RAID-ами и SSD RAID-ами). Например тот же Raid-0 может дать прирост скорости при распаралеливании записи(в отдельных ситуациях - как HDD так и SSD). Еще раз: тема СЛОЖНАЯ. Что бы что-то говорить наверняка нужны тесты. В идеале на том железе, под которое пишется программа. А в теоретические утверждения я не поверю. Автора вопроса я предупредил именно об этом своим ответом -- в том что код который он напишет может иметь противоположный эфект к желаемому.

Comment: Вот мне тоже очень интересно было-бы послушать, почему доступ к SSD не может быть параллельным? Прямо хочется технического обоснования. В случае с HDD, CD/DVD или кассетой в магнитофоне все понятно интуитивно. Сколько потоков не запусти, головка-то одна. А с SSD что не так? Почему доступ к данным, лежащим на SSD не может быть параллельным? Но ответ пока такой — нет и всё. Может, @avp заглянет в вопрос...

Comment: @АртёмОконечников Допустим это и вправду приведет к приросту скорости по какой-то причине. На топовых SSD, например. И здесь мы уже упремся в ограничение шины) Если ссд подключен по SATA - мы не получим убыстрения процесса т.к. топовые ссд и так работают на максимальной скорости SATA шины. А если по m2 - то хз что будет. Но снова таки - не у всех стоят топовые ссд и не у всех они на m2.

Comment: А еще мне кажется что если бы это реально приводило к увеличению скорости, то это реализовали бы уже давно на апаратном уровне или на уровне драйвера. А это значит что распаралеливание на высоком програмном уровне было бы бесполезным в таком случае.

Comment: @АртёмОконечников ну вот, аэпот подтердил мою догадку на практике - вероятно или драйвер или железо ставит ограничение и все равно делает в одном потоке)

Comment: Я уже туда плюс поставил, ага. Но мне было интересно именно _со стороны железки_ ограничения понять. Потому что сейчас особых отличий SSD от RAM я не вижу. В принципе, можно предположить почему так в драйвере сделано. Все-таки у нас R/W, а файлы ресурс разделяемый и т.д.

Comment: отличия есть и весьма приличные. Это же разные виды памяти в принципе. Flash Memory в любом случае будет медленнее за DRAM. Современная оператива может иметь скорость и в 20GB/s, которая просто недоступна SSD. Хотя когда-то практиковали SSD на основе плашек оперативки, но туда приходилось впихивать еще и аккумулятор. Кроме того нормальные материнки еще и разделяют оперативку по каналам, а это значит что максимальная скорость растет еще более т.к. общая ширина канала менее ограничена. Это можно увидеть когда шины под оперативку разделены по цветам слотов - один цвет - один канал.

Comment: Я возможно криво мысль свою описал. RAM просто память с произвольным доступом. С произвольным _за одинаковое_ время. В HDD логика понятная — одна головка — параллельно не почитаешь. Время доступа к файлам тоже разное в зависимости от их расположения на диске (физически). Я полез читать  вики, там и про RAM SSD нашел и вот это нашел: «количество произвольных операций ввода-вывода в секунду выше... за счёт возможности одновременного запуска множества операций».

Answer (score 4):

Просто скину как один из вариантов

```
if (searchOption == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
{
    IEnumerable<string> subDirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(rootPath);
    return subDirs.Concat(subDirs.AsParallel().SelectMany(dir => GetDirectoryFiles(dir, patternMatch, searchOption)));
}
```

Код не запускал, так что пробуйте сами.

Comment: В этом коде проблема в том, что в случае ошибки (неавторизованный доступ к одной из папок/файлов) не будет получен ни один файл.

Comment: Я показал принцип, конструкции try-catch уже есть в самом вопросе.