# Не получается исключить папки из поиска

Tags: c#

Список папок которые нужно обойти при поиске (не показывать их)

```
public static readonly string[] BypassDir = new string[]
{
   "Microsoft", "History", "Temp", 
};
```

Метод которым ищу файлы с "обходом"

```
public static List<string> GetAllFiles(string path, string pattern, SearchOption so = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
{
   var files = new List<string>();

   try
   {
       foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, pattern, so))
       {
          var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
          files.Add(file);          
       }
       foreach (string fl in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, "*", so))
       {
          if (!BypassDir.Contains(fl, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
          //if (!BypassDir.Any(ext => ext != Path.GetExtension(fl)))
          {
             files.AddRange(GetAllFiles(fl, pattern, so));
          }
       }
   }
       catch { }
       return files;
}
```

Но при сканирование всё ровно проходит папки, как исключить их правильно?

Comment: У вас в массиве простые слова, допустим, `Microsoft`, а `fl` небось целый путь (`c:\SomeDir\Microsoft`). Задайте теперь себе вопрос, есть ли в `BypassDir` значение `c:\SomeDir\Microsoft`? В строке, что вы закомментировали, там вы пошли в верном направление, только что такое `GetExtension()`? Что вообще такое `Extension`? Верно, это все, что идет после точки (`.exe`например), ну так почему сверяете название директории и расширение?

Comment: В тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1235165/373567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> if (!BypassDir.Contains(fl, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
> ```

```
if (!BypassDir.Contains(Path.GetFileName(fl), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

А вообще, лучше сделать `BypassDir` не массивом, а `Set`ом.

Comment: `HashSet` ? Если да, то почему именно им? И как тогда его использовать? Так же как со `string[]` ?

Comment: @GooliveR, потому что при большом количестве элементов поиск в нём эффективнее, чем  в массиве.