# Как пропустить файлы при удалении, которые открыты в другой программе c#?

Tags: c#, файлы

```
string userRoot = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE"); 

string paths = string.Format("{0}\\AppData\\Local\\Temp", userRoot); 

DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(paths); 

foreach (FileInfo file in folder.GetFiles()) 

{ 

        file.Delete(); 

} 

foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in folder.GetDirectories()) 

{ 

        dir.Delete(true); 

}
```

Это мой код: он удаляет всё из папки %temp%

Есть вопрос: при удалении находятся файлы, которые открыты в системных программах. Так вот, можно ли сделать так, чтобы при виде таких файлов c# их просто пропускал?

Comment: В `try/catch` оберните. А вообще, если есть такие файлы, и их надо удалить, то стоит подумать о том, как это обойти, например, можно попробовать использовать `MoveFileEx` с флагом `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT` из WinAPI, для того, чтоб пометить файл на удаление после перезагрузки компьютера ([пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1007224/6808809)). Так вот удалять файлы, без ожидания завершения процесса, оставлять следы, ну.. Странное решение.

Comment: Использовать перегрузку [GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=net-7.0#system-io-directoryinfo-getfiles(system-string-system-io-enumerationoptions)) с параметром `new EnumerationOptions { IgnoreInaccessible = true }`. PS: лучше использовать метод `EnumerateFiles`.

Comment: [Path.GetTempPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath)

Comment: Прошу обратить внимание, что Path.GetTempPath - статический метод статического объекта, лучше по возможности избегать применения.

Comment: @rotabor вы написали странное. Почему? А что по поводу Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable?

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться следующим алгоритмом как одним из вариантов решения:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace NsSkipFiles {
    class SkipFiles {
        static void DeleteDirectory(DirectoryInfo folder) {
            foreach (FileInfo file in folder.GetFiles()) try { file.Delete(); } catch { }
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in folder.GetDirectories()) DeleteDirectory(dir);
            try { folder.Delete(); } catch { }
        }
        static void Main() {
            DeleteDirectory(new DirectoryInfo(
                string.Format("{0}\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"
                    , Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE")))); 
        }
    }
}
```

Метод DeleteDirectory вызывается рекурсивно. В нём сначала удаляются файлы в папке, потом удалятся подпапки рекурсивным вызовом, потом удаляется сама папка. Файлы, которые заблокированы другими приложениями, игнорируются с помощью try catch. Такой алгоритм позволяет избежать случаев, когда удаление всех остальных элементов в папке отменяется из-за наличия одного заблокированного файла или папки.

Comment: Если folder.Delete упадёт, то не все возможные файлы будут удалены. Здесь рекурсия только решит задачу. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1235165/373567

Comment: @aepot folder.Delete вызывается после того, как из этого folder сначала удалены все файлы, а потом все подпапки. И тогда  folder.Delete будет успешно выполнен (если папка не заблокирована/есть доступ). То есть задача folder.Delete лишь удалить саму папку (пустую). Таким образом всё, что может быть удалено, будет удалено

Comment: Возможно я что-то проглядел, тяжело читать C#, отформатированный как JavaScript, да еще и операндами в одну строку.